# python packages and imports, import error from module

Tags: python, setuptools, conda-build

I am packaging a python package using `conda-build` and ran into some issues. I am probably missing something fundamental and would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

The package looks like

```
|foo
  |meta.yaml
  |build.sh
  |build.bat
  |foo
    |__init__.py
    |module_1
    |module_2
    |-submodule
        |module_3
        |__init__.py
    |setup.py
```

module_1 looks like

```
import module_2

def fun:
    print(module2.__name__)
```

If I import the package from a parent folder like:

```
from foo import module_1
```

I get the error: `module_2 not found`

If I rewrite the import like `import foo.module_2` everyhting works fine. Is this the proper way to handle inter package imports ?

Comment: Try a relative import like `from . import module_2`. If this is Python 3, absolute imports like `import module_2` would not be treated as package-relative.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if it's just a mistake in your formatting, but your ASCII art makes it look like you have a `setup.py` *inside* the package. It should be outside the package.

Comment: That is another thing i currently try to understand. I guess I should try conda skeleton

Comment: What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: I get `/home/moritz/anaconda3/conda-bld/cadet_match_1541412717213/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold/bin/python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` when setup.py is in the parent directory. I guess something in the meta.yaml is wrong. I will make another questions and reference here.

Comment: It might has to to something with the ${PREFIX} variable. and how conda_build.sh is generated

Comment: Probably a problem in your conda stuff. `setup.py` should *never* go inside a package, and should only be at the root level of your source tree. It *describes* a package but is not part of the package.